# Verify the moveToElement or the clickandHold is working

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did several method to do the hover action but I need a way to verify if the method worked, and if that is not the case going to the other method.

I used this code to verify but is not working:

```
return zQuery(arguments[0]).attr('data-functionize-hover');
```

I think that a script that track if the dom changed but not sure if that is possible.

Thanks!!

Comment: I used the MouseNightWatch to see  but on safari dont work and something get fails too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify move to element you can try implementing the following scenario:

1. Perform move to element action using `Actions (import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;)`

   ```
   WebElement elToHover = driver.findElement(By.id("add_element_id_here"));
   Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   actions.moveToElement(elToHover).perform();
   ```
2. Verify something changed

In case you need to check some attributes of the element we hovered in step 1:

```
assertEquals(elToHover.getAttribute('attribute-name-you-want-to-check', "value you expext");
```

In case you need to check some other element:

```
WebElement anotherEl = driver.findElement(By.id("add_another_element_id_here"));
assertTrue(anotherEl.isDisplayed());
```

Comment: Tks Vladimir, I thought isDisplayed will be a good option and that is the best one on my mind but the issue is that I am not able to get the next element xpath or name until now and I think I am going to mark as answer because I dont have another idea.

Comment: @Rafa it will be possible to suggest more precisely if you provide HTML sample for 2 states of your app 1) before hover 2) when hovering

Comment: yes, but on this case it is an app that test random pages so can be any website that have a hover for example amazon, youtube or salesforce.